# How to generate .deb of ROS package step by step outside ros buildfarm

Tags: ros, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
Can anyone provide a tutorial to generate a .deb of a ROS package step by step so that the others can use it to install the package without source code.

Many thanks,
Rickardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241663/how-to-generate-.deb-of-ros-package-step-by-step-outside-ros-buildfarm/) by [rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23936/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-08-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2018-01-03**:
Hey Rikardo, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to build a ROS package into a deb, you can do it just like any debian package manually I highly recommend reading through the Debian documentation. There's a relatively steep learning curve unfortunately.

A few starting points are:

- https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian
- https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html
- https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/debian-packaging.html

I don't know what your use case is, but if you're building ROS packages privately you can still use bloom to generate a lot of the boilerplate needed above. And you can use [git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.html) to build the resultant debian packages locally in approximately one line.

A simpler approach that can fill many use cases is to use the [checkinstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) tool. You can use checkinstall with the install target for a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way I have found to do this is by using CPack which is a CMake module.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html

In one of your CMakeLists.txt files you can add the following to generate a .deb

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${PACKAGE_NAME})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "${PACKAGE_NAME} debian package")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAINTAINER}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "${${PROJECT_NAME}_MAINTAINER}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

include(CPack)
```

Note that this will create a debian from your entire catkin workspace as all of the CMakeLists.txt files are merged into one when using catkin (although it might be possible to get round this using catkin_make_isolated).

---

Originally posted by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) with karma: 154 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2